# Google Analytics unable to validate my site during setup

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Analytics unable to validate my site during setup](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19742/google-analytics-unable-to-validate-my-site-during-setup)

I had trouble setting up GA on one of my websites so I set up a very simple test environment with a new domain name and just a single page - the default page.  Even in this simple environment I couldn't get GA to validate me.

My environment is as follows:

Site: www.example.com
My default page contains the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-25700000-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();

</script>
</head>
example.com Google Analytics test
</html>
```

I am 10000000% sure that the tracking code provided to me is the tracking code included in the above script.  I simply copied and pasted the code block.

I've waited days after doing the config since I know it may take GA time, but certainly shouldn't take 3 days.

The old version of GA shows:

[image]

and the new version shows:

[image]

Note that the screenshot of the new version has the weird "December 1969" thing which I've read about in other forums and seems (?) unrelated to my problem.

How can I make this work?